# Paging (oracle database)

Tags: oracle, request, paging

I need to create request to oracle database from my C# code what will select rows for pages at web site. I want for example for get rows from 100 to 200 for second page. 
I found some code what real works

```
SELECT * FROM
(
   SELECT a.*, rownum r__
   FROM
   (
      SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE CustomerID LIKE 'A%'
      ORDER BY OrderDate DESC, ShippingDate DESC
   ) a
   WHERE rownum < ((pageNumber * pageSize) + 1 )
)
WHERE r__ >= (((pageNumber-1) * pageSize) + 1)
```

It works, I can use it when change this block inside wrap

```
SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE CustomerID LIKE 'A%'
ORDER BY OrderDate DESC, ShippingDate DESC
```

But how does it work? I can't understand. I'm familiar with SQL requests but what is

```
SELECT a.*, rownum r__
```

and what is

```
 ) a
```

after FROM wrap?

Can you be so kind to explain me this wrap?

Comment: you might also benefit from setting `optimizer_mode=FIRST_ROWS`. i would also recommend looking into the analytic function `row_number()` for that purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select a.*, rownum    ->Select all records from table/table alias a, along with rownumber, so you can select a subset.

(SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE CustomerID LIKE 'A%'
      ORDER BY OrderDate DESC, ShippingDate DESC) a

Creates 'a' as a table alias allowing you to treat it as a table in outer select table.

As a note, select * is considered bad practice as changes to the table structure will likely break your code.

Comment: [A subquery in the FROM clause of a SELECT statement is also called an inline view.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/queries007.htm)

Comment: Good idea about select * will break code when we change something in table structure. And thanks for answer. Everything becomes a bit more clear =)